# SQLite UPDATE two tables from VIEW or TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: select, update, sqlite, temporary-tables

Here is the query that doesn't compile just to show how it should look like. But since I can't do Multiple table `UPDATE`'s.

This fake query should be able to run the inner `UPDATE`'s for both tables if only a row exists from the inner `SELECT`. Then all those `UPDATE`'s should be ran by 1 select at a time that's why the inner select has a `LIMIT 1`.. because if it selects more then one row at a time the next row match could be wrong or duplicate Seller (who is suppose to be unavailable) for a new Buyer from previous rows.

Should run those `UPDATE`'s with the outer `LIMIT` of `100` each time (not guaranteed there will be 100 but it's a fair limit)

Also like to add that the amount a Buyer can buy from a Seller is randomized by the max amount that Buyer can buy subtracted from max amount seller can sell which is subtracted from amount that seller already sold..

I can't update the Seller's `sold` column or Buyer's `bought` column until I do some other queries with the program I'm building.

The query doesn't have I could add this myself later, to sell to Buyer's who pay the most money first.

```
SELECT * FROM Buying AS BB, Selling AS SS 
WHERE (
   UPDATE Buying, Selling
   SET Buying.boughtPending = Buying.boughtPending + willBuyAmount,
   SET Selling.soldPending = Selling.soldPending + willBuyAmount
      WHERE EXISTS (
           SELECT
                  CASE
                       WHEN( B.amount - B.bought ) >( S.amount - S.sold ) THEN( 1 + ABS( RANDOM(  ) %( S.amount - S.sold )  )  ) 
                       ELSE( 1 + ABS( RANDOM(  ) %( B.amount - B.bought )  )  ) 
                  END AS willBuyAmount
             FROM Buying AS B, 
                  Selling AS S
           ON B.itemId = S.itemId 
           AND
           B.aborted = 0 
           AND
           S.aborted = 0 
           AND
           B.boughtPending = 0 
           AND
           S.soldPending = 0 
           AND
           B.price >= S.price 
           AND
           S.sold < S.amount 
           AND
           B.bought < B.amount
           LIMIT 1 
      )
  ) AND BB.boughtPending > 0 AND SS.soldPending > 0 LIMIT 100;
```

I started trying out this new way to just get one match UPDATED (then I'd have to run this 100 times somehow. (doubt i'll be using `VIEW`'s for this because I'll have to keep destroying them everytime I need to `UPDATE` (still doesn't work for just one match)

Error:

> Error while executing query: no such column: sale.willBuyAmount

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP VIEW sale AS
       SELECT CASE
                   WHEN( B.amount - B.bought ) >( S.amount - S.sold ) THEN( 1 + ABS( RANDOM(  ) %( S.amount - S.sold )  )  ) 
                   ELSE( 1 + ABS( RANDOM(  ) %( B.amount - B.bought )  )  ) 
              END AS willBuyAmount,
              B.id AS buyerId,
              S.id AS sellerId
         FROM Buying AS B, 
              Selling AS S
       ON B.itemId = S.itemId 
       AND
       B.aborted = 0 
       AND
       S.aborted = 0 
       AND
       B.boughtPending = 0 
       AND
       S.soldPending = 0 
       AND
       B.price >= S.price 
       AND
       S.sold < S.amount 
       AND
       B.bought < B.amount
       LIMIT 1;

UPDATE Buying   
SET boughtPending = boughtPending + sale.willBuyAmount  
WHERE sale.buyerId = id;

UPDATE Selling    
SET soldPending = soldPending + sale.willBuyAmount  
WHERE sale.sellerId = id;

DROP VIEW sales;

COMMIT;
```

here is my table DDL's

```
CREATE TABLE Buying ( 
    id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    itemId        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    bought        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    boughtPending INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    collectedItem INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    collectedGold INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    overpaid      INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    slot          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aborted       BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    playerHash    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ( slot, playerHash ) 
);

CREATE TABLE Selling ( 
    id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    itemId        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    sold          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    soldPending   INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    collectedItem INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    collectedGold INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    overpaid      INTEGER NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    slot          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aborted       BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT ( 0 ),
    playerHash    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ( slot, playerHash ) 
);
```

Comment: Have you tried prototyping the query in smaller sections instead of creating one big blob. Additionally have you tried creating a temporary table instead of a temporary view in your second example.

Comment: I haven't created a temporary table because I still haven't figured out how to use those.. `VIEW`'s seem to do the same as I would use the temporary table for to view variables in a different query (`UPDATE`). Only thing is in a temporary table I would have to do a `CREATE`.. then `INSERT`.. then DROP TABLE at the end.. in VIEW I just run one command for `CREATE+INSERT` (I still don't know if this is why you use `VIEW` for). I also don't know how to `INSERT` from a `SELECT`.. so yeah I jsut need some help some examples if you have.

Comment: You can't store data in a view, it is a way of storing a query to get a 'VIEW' of the data you are interested in. A temporary table is just that, a table, thus you can run all the table operations against it. I recommend making heavy use of the MySql online documentation and trying out a few things yourself. See this SO question for how to do an INSERT..SELECT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select